# How to add markers to OPENLAYERS map with JSON coordinates?

Tags: javascript, json, openlayers-3, markers

I am trying to zoom and add markers to a HTML openlayers map, so far I hardcoded the lat and long pulled from JSON result.
I would like in a first place to drop a marker at the location and then using lat and lng to create a function to avoid harcoding and being able to drop a marker for any JSON entry.

Here is my code so far, the location is well zoomed to the location but cant find how to drop a marker? Thanks!

```
 var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
   new ol.layer.Tile({
   source: new ol.source.OSM()})
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
   center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([103.835471, 1.303371]),
   zoom: 6
  }),
 target: 'map'
});
```

Comment: How about a feedback?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the basic steps you want to follow:

- Create a vector layer ([`ol.layer.Vector`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html)) with a vector source ([`ol.source.Vector`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html))
- Include the layer in your map's "layers" array
- Create a feature ([`ol.Feature`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.Feature.html)) with the desired geometry
- Call [`addFeature()`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#addFeature) on your vector source to add the feature to the layer

Make sure you transform the coordinates for your geometry if they are lat/lon.

The following may be helpful:

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/icon.html

Comment: Thanks , as soon as I start injecting vectorLayer in my array I get a console error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'closure_uid_152235684' of undefined" . I wrote it like that : 

layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()}), vectorLayer
  ],

Comment: @sarah_g how about a fiddle?